# How to route error page to an URL containing hashtag using Nginx

Tags: nginx, routes

I'm a beginner in Nginx. I'm working on a single page app using Angular 2, in which I created a PageNotFound view at `/#/page_not_found`, how do I configure Nginx so that when 404, route to `/#/page_not_found`? Nginx doesn't seem to like hashtag in url, so I couldn't do `error_page 404 /#/page_not_found`
I could route it as if it is an external url by doing

```
error_page 404 "http://my_public_domain_name/#/page_not_found";
```

But this looks like a hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `error_page` to generate an external redirect, as you are handling the error client side.

You already have the solution, but you can make the statement more generalised by using predefined variables:

```
error_page 404 $scheme://$host/#/page_not_found;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for the `error_page` directive, and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) for a list of variables.